# Missing entity when retrieving data from Server database from API controller

Tags: c#, api, controller, odata, get-request

I am writing an audit log controller for a C# solution where the API retrieves all the audit logs from the Server through a repository.  I am able to retrieve all audit logs except the ones that in the column "IsDeleted" are true.  I am attaching screenshots of all of my code and the Postman get request so you can see for yourself.  I currently have 11 entities in the data table, but 10 are being retrieved.
P.S.  We are using this [String To Expression](https://github.com/codecutout/StringToExpression) library (similar to OData) so that's where the attributes and parameters are coming from.

Audit Logs Controller:

```
        [HttpGet]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(PaginatedList<AuditLogViewModel>), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [Produces("application/json")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status422UnprocessableEntity)]
        [ProducesDefaultResponseType]
        public PaginatedList<AuditLog> Get(
        [FromQuery(Name = "$filter")] string filter = "",
        //order audit logs by date
        [FromQuery(Name = "$orderby")] string orderBy = "Timestamp desc",
        [FromQuery(Name = "$top")] int top = 100,
        [FromQuery(Name = "$skip")] int skip = 0
        )
        {
            //TODO: use AuditLogViewModel instead of AuditLog model
            return base.GetMany();
        }
```

The GetMany() method just returns a paginated list of all of the audit logs from the Server.

```
protected virtual PaginatedList<T> GetMany(string parentid = "")
        {
            ODataHelper<T> oData = new ODataHelper<T>();

            string queryString = "";

            if (HttpContext != null
                && HttpContext.Request != null
                && HttpContext.Request.QueryString != null
                && HttpContext.Request.QueryString.HasValue)
                queryString = HttpContext.Request.QueryString.Value;

            oData.Parse(queryString);
            Guid parentguid = Guid.Empty;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parentid))
                parentguid = new Guid(parentid);

            return readRepository.Find(parentguid, oData.Filter, oData.Sort, oData.SortDirection, oData.Skip, oData.Top);
```

Here is the Find() method used inside of the GetMany() method:

```
 public virtual PaginatedList<T> Find(Guid? parentId = null, Func<T, bool> predicate = null, Func<T, object> sort = null, OrderByDirectionType direction = OrderByDirectionType.Ascending, int skip = 0, int take = 0)
        {
            PaginatedList<T> list = new PaginatedList<T>();

            if (skip == 0 || take == 0)
            {
                list.PageNumber = 0;
                list.PageSize = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                int pageNumber = skip;
                if (skip != 0 && take != 0)
                    pageNumber = skip / take;

                list.PageNumber = pageNumber;
                list.PageSize = take;
            }

            IQueryable<T> resultSet;
            if (predicate != null)
                resultSet = GetMany(predicate, parentId);
            else
                resultSet = GetMany(null, parentId);

            int totalCount = resultSet.Count();
            list.TotalCount = totalCount;

            if (sort != null)
            {
                if (direction == OrderByDirectionType.Ascending)
                    resultSet = resultSet.OrderBy(sort).AsQueryable();
                else
                    resultSet = resultSet.OrderByDescending(sort).AsQueryable();
            }

            if (skip != 0)
                resultSet = resultSet.Skip(skip);

            if (take != 0)
                resultSet = resultSet.Take(take);

            list.Items = resultSet.ToList();

            return list;
```

There is another GetMany() IQueryable method that is used in the Find() method.  This is where the issue lies that the deleted ones do not pop up:

```
protected IQueryable<T> GetMany(Func<T, bool> predicate = null, Guid? parentId = null)
        {
            IQueryable<T> resultSet = DbTable().AsQueryable();

            if (parentId.HasValue && parentId.Value != Guid.Empty)
                resultSet = resultSet.Where(ParentFilter(parentId.Value)).AsQueryable();

            resultSet = resultSet.Where(RemoveSoftDeleted()).AsQueryable();
            resultSet = AuthorizeRows(resultSet.Where(AuthorizeRead()).AsQueryable());

            if (predicate != null)
                resultSet = resultSet.Where(predicate).AsQueryable();

            return resultSet;
        }
```

[Postman Get Request & Results Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsfOt.png)

[Audit Logs Data Table (11 Entities)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DX9Fl.png)

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated, as I am still learning more about String to Expressions and OData.

Comment: The obvious reason is because `isDeleted=false`... Could you post the method (GetMany) which actually get's the list? I almost bet this is excluding records that *are* deleted.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ It has been updated to show the methods used within the controller.

Comment: What does `queryString` look like?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Now that I am looking at it there is another GetMany() method that removed the deleted entities.  Because it is protected how would I override this?

Comment: You'd have to make `GetMany` `virtual`, then you can override it.

Comment: Nevermind, it is not necessary for those to come up because it is representing a soft delete in the data table, not that the entity itself has been changed by being deleted.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, I wouldn't have been able to guess that from here.